# Applying known proofs in Idris 1 interactive elaborator

Tags: idris, theorem-proving

I am trying to get some familiarity with theorem proving in Idris1 by exercise and am running into trouble.

Suppose I have the following definition for naturals and the following theorems that I want to prove:

```
data Natural = Z | S Natural

plus : Natural -> Natural -> Natural
plus x Z = x
plus x (S y) = S (plus x y)

succBoth : {a : Natural} -> {b : Natural} -> (a = b) -> (S a = S b)
succBoth = ?succBothProof

plusZero : (y : Natural) -> plus Z y = y
plusZero = ?plusZeroProof

plusSwitch : (x : Natural) -> (y : Natural) -> plus (S x) y = S (plus x y)
plusSwitch = ?plusSwitchProof

plusComm : (x : Natural) -> (y : Natural) -> plus x y = plus y x
plusComm = ?plusCommProof
```

I already have written proofs for the first three. Now, when I want to prove the last theorem, I run into necessity of applying an earlier proof.

```
Idris> :l Peano.idr
Holes: Peano.plusCommProof
*Peano> :elab plusCommProof
-Peano.plusCommProof> intro `{{x}}
...
-Peano.plusCommProof> intro `{{y}}
...
-Peano.plusCommProof> induction (Var `{{y}})
...
-Peano.plusCommProof> compute
...
-Peano.plusCommProof> attack
----------              Other goals:              ----------
{Z_103},{S_104}
----------              Assumptions:              ----------
 x : Natural
 y : Natural
----------                 Goal:                  ----------
{hole_7} : x = plus Z x
```

It would be natural to apply `plusZero` at this stage, but I run into issues trying to do that. I try to apply it via `rewriteWith`, keeping in mind that `plusZero` takes a `Natural` type argument. I try to supply it with the `x` variable, thinking that it will be able to infer its `Natural` type from assumptions, but no luck:

```
-Peano.plusCommProof> rewriteWith `(plusZero (Var `{{x}}))
(input):1:15-35:When checking argument y to function Peano.plusZero:
        Type mismatch between
                Raw (Type of Var _)
        and
                Natural (Expected type)
```

How does one "cast" the `Raw` variable into its type in context?

Comment: I don't know elab stuff, but `plusComm Z x = rewrite plusZero x in Refl` type checks for me

Comment: btw I can't find `rewriteWith` in the Idris source. Are you using Idris2?

Comment: No, this is Idris(1) with ElabReflection. `rewriteWith`:
https://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/elaboratorReflection/primitive.html
I thought this monad was how you are supposed to write proofs now (Idris complains about deprecation otherwise)

Comment: it's recommended to use idris2 now. I can't comment on elab at all

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the Idris 1 version to work but I did install Idris 2 and wrote the proofs in its style instead.

```
module Peano

data Natural = Zero | Succ Natural

plus : Natural -> Natural -> Natural
plus x Zero = x
plus x (Succ y) = Succ (plus x y)

succBoth : {a : Natural} -> {b : Natural} -> (a = b) -> (Succ a = Succ b)
succBoth rfl = cong (\ a => Succ a) rfl

plusZero : (y : Natural) -> plus Zero y = y
plusZero Zero = Refl
plusZero (Succ y)
  = let assumption = plusZero y in
        rewrite assumption in Refl

plusSwitch : (x : Natural) -> (y : Natural) ->
             plus (Succ x) y = Succ (plus x y)
plusSwitch x Zero = Refl
plusSwitch x (Succ y)
  = let assumption = plusSwitch x y in
        rewrite assumption in Refl

plusComm : (x : Natural) -> (y : Natural) -> plus x y = plus y x
plusComm x Zero = rewrite plusZero x in Refl
plusComm x (Succ y)
  = let assumption = plusComm x y in
        rewrite plusSwitch y x in
        rewrite assumption in Refl
```

Admittedly much more compact but I prefer the Idris 1 :elab style for readability